# Electronic band structure of proteins

Tags: solid-state-physics, biophysics, electronic-band-theory

Proteins are a class of macromolecules. What range of electronic band structure do These have? Are These more like semiconductors? Or like insulators? How high is the typical Fermi Level for Proteins?

Mentioning "Proteins" is quite General, but I think the Variety in electronic band structure should not be so high for biological tissue.

Any answers would be acknowledged.

Answer (score 4):

"Band structure" is a concept of collective excitations in a crystal.  The repetition of the crystal, its "point group", dictates many properties of the band structure.

Proteins are very large molecules.  We normally speak of the excitations of a molecule as "molecular orbitals".  While a protein molecule might be big, it is not so big as to be well described by macroscopic properties like conductor, insulator and semiconductor.

Similarly, while a semiconductor has a fermi level describing which band structure states are occupied, a large molecule would be better described by it HOMO and LUMO - being the highest occupied molecular orbital and the lowest unoccupied molecular orbital.

Now, to be honest, some molecules are just so big that even molecular orbital theory is not useful and one must get .... creative?   But, because a molecule is not a crystal, band theory is not the droid that you are looking for.